# Jackson xml serialize map that key contains whitespace

Tags: xml, generics, dictionary, serialization, jackson

i use Jackson 2.5.2 and i have a `map<String,String>`

by default, Jackson serializes it into :

```
<MyObject>
 <map> 
  <key1>value1</key1> 
  <key2 containing spaces>value2</key2 containing spaces>
 <map>
</MyObject>
```

but i want a generic xml tag :

```
<MyObject>
 <map> 
  <entry key="key1">value1</entry>
  <entry key="key2 containing spaces">value2</entry>
 <map>
</MyObject>
```

in this way my xml tags are generic and can be validated with xsd

here is my test

```
class MyObject {
    Map map = new HashMap();  
    public Map getMap() { return map;}
}
// Test
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.getMap().put("key1","value1");
myObject.getMap().put("key2 containing spaces","value2");
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject));
```

is there any configuration to tell Jackson to serialize generic xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to file a bug report for this problem: what is done for property names is to replace offending characters like spaces with something else (or strip them). But there is the problem of reliably converting names back; in case of properties that is easy enough (just map modified/stripped names), but for Maps it may or may not be possible.